# Logging eth.syncing.currentBlock and highestBlock

Tags: go-ethereum

I'd to like `currentBlock` and `highestBlock` from geth using `geth attach --exec` to run this script for pickup by Telegraf:

#### `blocks.sh`

```
/usr/bin/geth --datadir /home/ethereum/.ethereum --jspath /home/ethereum --exec 'loadScript("blocks.js")' attach | head -n -1
```

#### `blocks.js`

```
if (eth.syncing) {
    console.log("blocks,network=" + admin.nodeInfo.protocols.eth.network + " current=" + eth.syncing.currentBlock + ",highest=" + eth.syncing.highestBlock);
}

console.log("peers count=" + net.peerCount);
```

And the output (in Influx line protocol format) looks like:

```
blocks,network=1 current=2194411,highest=5119467
peers count=5
```

However, they're only available when `eth.syncing` is not false, which, after a full sync is not very often. Is there somewhere else to get those values that's always available?

Comment: Can you clarify if you're referring to [Telegraf by influx data](https://www.influxdata.com/time-series-platform/telegraf/)?

Comment: Yes, I have a script that uses `geth attach --exec` to output `blocks,network=1 current=18462,highest=5119418`.

Comment: Can you edit your original post to include this information?

Comment: Alright, but it's mostly irrelevant to the question.